# jQuery live bind without event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
  testfunc: function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      alert("testfunc!");
    });
  }
});
$("#container").on('click', "button", function() {
  $(this).testfunc();
});

$("#container").append('<button class="dynamic-buttons"  type="button" >button2</button>');
$("#container").append('<button class="dynamic-buttons"  type="button" >button3</button>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <button class="dynamic-buttons" type="button">button</button>
</div>
```

I have a jQuery function, which is not allowed to change. I need to use the function for dynamic created html objects. the on() function need to bind a event, but my function already have the click event, here is the problem!

Comment: It's not clear what you want/ask?

Comment: Why you're using the `click` event twice?

Comment: Yes. What do you exactly want? By looking at your code, when you first click the button, another click event is binded, then again clicking on button, binded event triggers and again event is binded..This is not good practice

Comment: I don't want to use click twice! I want to find a way working as on() function, without bind the second event. @Amiut7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/aqLstehj/3/

Check this out

You need to bind event of 'DOMNodeInserted'

```
$(document).on("DOMNodeInserted", "#container button", function() {
    $(this).testfunc();
})
```

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted, please read this if anyone use this solution. I haven't find better one.